# Type cast optional values

Tags: swift

Whenever we need to du something with an optional value in swift we need to unwrap it to operate, not on the optional, but on the value ”inside” the optional.

```
var optionalString:String? = "Hello"
optionalString!.append(" World!")
```

Note the exclamation mark on the second line.

But when using the optional type cast operator (as?) on an optional value, one does not need to unwrap the optional, we just provide it with the optional itself, and it just magically works.

```
let sneakyString:Any? = "Hello!"
let notSoSneakyString = sneakyString as? String
```

Note the absent exclamation mark on the second line.

The magic is a bit more obvious if we spell it out:

```
let sneakyString:Any? = Optional("Hello")
let notSoSneakyString = sneakyString as? String
```

Its not a string we're trying to cast but an enum with a string as an associated value.

I would expect that I would have to do this:

```
let sneakyString:Any? = "Hello!"
let notSoSneakyString = sneakyString! as? String
```

Note the exclamation mark on the second line.

Does the type cast operators act on optionals and non optionals in the same way?

Comment: Maybe this makes sense after all. To unwrap a nil optional is a runtime error. And we’re not casting from Optional(Any) to String, but from Optional(Any) to Optional(String).

Answer (score 3):

The `as?` operator makes a cast if it possibly can, and returns either the casted object or `nil`. It handles nil values too, so that if `sneakyString` were nil, you wouldn't have been able to cast it to a `String` and the cast would have failed. Same behaviour as if it were non-nil but not castable to `String`.

In other words, you don't need the `!` because `as?` handles nil values automatically itself.

Comment: Yea the nil case is a bit more logical. Edited my question to point out that the operator is not operating on a string struct, but on an enum with a string as an associated value. Do you know if this is documented?